# crate name has a dash : unresolved import error

Tags: rust

Probably a very rookie question (I'm not much of a rust developer).

The source file has

```
use rustc_hash::FxHashMap;
```

and the parent directory contains `Cargo.toml` that includes

```
[dependencies]
rustc-hash = "1.0"
```

When I run `cargo build` in that parent directory, it seems to install `rustc-hash`, but I still get this error as if no dependencies were specified.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rustc_hash`
...
maybe a missing crate `rustc_hash`?
```

On the other hand, when I try to use an underscore

```
[dependencies]
rustc_hash = "1.0"
```

`cargo` can't find this crate:

```
location searched: registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
perhaps you meant: rustc-hash
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (this is one of my first facepalm learning rust)

Comment: Do you have `edition = "2018"` in your Cargo.toml? `extern crate ...` should be unnecessary in Rust 2018.

Comment: @Cerberus Nope, no "edition". `cargo` and `rustc` version is `1.40.0`.

Comment: That means you have the 2015 edition rules - see https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/ for details. In 2018 edition, your code would possibly work as it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rustc-hash` is the correct way to declare the rustc-hash crate in your dependencies.

Ex:

`rustc-hash = { version = "1.0", default-features = false }`

In your source code(lib.rs and/or main.rs) you need to declare `extern crate rustc_hash;`, followed by the relevant `use` statements.

Ex:

```rust
extern crate rustc_hash;
use rustc_hash::FxHashMap;
```

Comment: In the Rust 2018 dialect you can mostly avoid "extern crate" unless the crate contains macros you need to use.